# Why does <a> tag content overflows containing div boundaries?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve a horizontal menu with unordered list inside a div. The problem is that  tags overflow (are bigger) then containing div. Or, seen from other side, the div does take into account the full size of  tags.

Css

```
div.menu {
    background: grey;
}
div.menu > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.menu > ul > li {
    display: inline;
}
div.menu > ul > li > a:link, div.menu > ul > li > a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
        </li>
        <li>No overspill
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7cosy2t/2/)

The problem has something to do with padding, because if I set the padding to 0 there is no overspill.
Why does this happen and what is the best practice to approach this?

Comment: @SleekGeek: Taller. it <a> tag extend above and below containing div. It is visible if you run JSFiddle example.

Comment: Add display:inline-block; to the a tag css

Comment: @It seems unfair that I can only accept one answer as each gave me another insight and those who answered did that at almost exactly same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the line of code below to your LI block of CSS code.

```
display: inline-block;
```

```css
div.menu {
    background: grey;
}
div.menu > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.menu > ul > li {
    display: inline;
}
div.menu > ul > li > a:link, div.menu > ul > li > a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block; /* This line solves the overlapping problem */
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
        </li>
        <li>No overspill
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding on inline elements doesn't affect the size of the element. The padding will just be visible around the element.

You can use `display: inline-block;` on the list items, and then `display: block;` on the links, that will include the padding in the size of the elements.

Another approach would be to use `float: left;` on the list items and `display: block;` on the links. It depends on how you want the layout, as that will put the links next to each other, not separated by spaces.

Comment: Tnx. This is the closest to explanation. So if I understand: on inline elements padding does not add to calculated site, but it is visible. Vaguely similar to margins, which can overlap.

Comment: @user3104537: Yes, it's similar to margins, except that the padding doesn't affect surrounding elements either. You can see an example of that on the yellow element at the bottom of this page: http://archive.webstandards.org/css/macie/inlinedemo1.html

Answer (score 0):

```
div.menu > ul > li > a{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Should fix the overflow.